# ¿Por qué no me deja copiar y pegar archivos diferente a txt en Python, usando la libreria watchdog?

Tags: python, windows, python-import

Estoy realizando un script con la libreria watchdog que vigile cualquier evento que suceda en la carpeta de "Descargas" de mi pc, ademas que cuando se muevan archivos a esa carpeta, dependiendo de su extension se cambie la localización del archivo (.mp3 a "Musica", .txt,.docx,.pdf a "Documentos" y .jpg, .png a "Imagenes")

En el momento que copio y pego una cancion(.mp3) o una imagen(.jpg) me arroja el siguiente error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso: 'C:/Users/**** ****/Downloads/Chet Faker - No Diggity.mp3' -> 'C:/Users/**** ****/Music/Chet Faker - No Diggity.mp3'
```

La cuestión es que si me sucediera lo mismo con los archivos de texto, pero no. Solo me arroja el error con canciones o imagenes. Recien estoy incursionando con esta libreria y no he encontrado información clara al respecto de mi problema.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import os

# List with all the ext and folders to use
EXT = [ ['txt','docx','pdf'],['jpg','png'],['mp3','wmv'] ]  #EXT--> 0: TEXTOS; 1: IMAGENES; 2:MUSICA
TARGET_FOLDERS = ['C:/Users/**** ****/Downloads','C:/Users/**** ****/Documents','C:/Users/**** ****/Pictures','C:/Users/**** ****/Music']

class myHandlr(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print(f"[Event type: {event.event_type}] [path: {event.src_path}]")

    def on_deleted(self, event):
        print(f"[Event type: {event.event_type}] [path: {event.src_path}]")
    
    def on_modified(self, event):
        '''
        Function which tracks each file of the Downloads folder

        Args:
        event: name of the event detected by the FileSystemEventHandler

        Returns a message depending of the action performed 
        '''
        for filename in os.listdir(path): # Recorre los archivos que se encuentran en la carpeta de
            aux = filename.split('.')     # descargas, lo divide en dos y transforma en una lista
            if aux[1] in EXT[0]:          # para poder determinar que extension es con un if 
                src = path + '/' + filename           
                new_src = str(TARGET_FOLDERS[1]) + '/' + filename
                os.rename(src, new_src)

                print(f"[Event type: {event.event_type}] {filename} Se ha movido de --> [path: {event.src_path}] a --> [path: {TARGET_FOLDERS[1]}]")
            elif aux[1] in EXT[1]:
                src = path + '/' + filename
                new_src = str(TARGET_FOLDERS[2]) + '/' + filename
                os.rename(src, new_src)

                print(f"[Event type: {event.event_type}] {filename} Se ha movido de --> [path: {event.src_path}] a --> [path: {TARGET_FOLDERS[2]}]")
            elif aux[1] in EXT[2]:
                src = path + '/' + filename
                new_src = str(TARGET_FOLDERS[3]) + '/' + filename
                os.rename(src, new_src)

                print(f"[Event type: {event.event_type}] {filename} Se ha movido de --> [path: {event.src_path}] a --> [path: {TARGET_FOLDERS[3]}]")
```

El main es el siguiente:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":  

# Initialize folder to observe, Handler and Observer object
path = str(TARGET_FOLDERS[0])
event_handler = myHandlr()
watcher = Observer()

# Set the schedule of the Observer object with its args
watcher.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)

# Starting the Observing object
watcher.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    watcher.stop()
watcher.join()
```

Comment: Hmm no puedo reproducir tu error. A lo mejor tu programa no puede modificar el archivo debido a que detecta la modificación mientras aún se está escribiendo. Puedes probar meterlo en un loop con un `sleep()` hasta que se pueda realizar la acción que quieres (a lo mejor con un límite de espera).

Comment: Añadiendo un sleep dentro del loop del for? ya que ahí es donde se realiza el procedimiento de mover los archivos.

Comment: Habrá alguna manera de determinar cuando se esté copiando archivos? para poder diferenciar estos procesos y tratarlos de manera apartada al proceso de simplemente mover archivos a la carpeta de descargas y de ahí se mueven a otras carpetas (proceso que funciona perfectamente)

Comment: Claro, sabes que está siendo escrito cuando obtienes ese error (alternativamente podría ser que tu proceso de Python no tiene permiso, pero eso es otro caso completamente). Lo puedes agarrar dentro de un bloque `try: ... except PermissionError: ... `

Comment: También puedes ver https://stackoverflow.com/a/11115521/11649862